# Opencv3 x64 visual studio read image but only display empty window

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015, 64-bit, opencv3.1

I had worked with OPENCV2.4.7 for a long time. Everything worked fine on my windows10 computer. Today, I download OPENCV3.2 and want to start using this version. Unfortunately, it did not work correctly even with simply read an image file and show it in a window. The code is like this:

```
cv::Mat image;
image = cv::imread("download.jpg"); 
if (image.empty())                      // Check for invalid input
{
    std::cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
std::cout << "image size is: " << image.rows << "x" << image.cols << std::endl;
std::cout << "image type is: " << image.type() << std::endl;

cv::namedWindow("Display window", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); // Create a window for display.
cv::imshow("Display window", image);                // Show our image inside it.
cv::waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
return 0;
```

I can see the image was loaded. The image size is correctly 240x292 and the image type is 16. However, the imshow() did not display the image but only a gray window. And the program seemed stuck there. I used visual studio 2015 and run program in x64. I also tried visual studio 2012 and opencv 3.0. The same problem happened all the time.

Any suggestion how to solve this problem?